# How can i get every "a" tag which "href" attribute contain word "youtube"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I want to catch every `a` tag which `href` attribute contain word `youtube`.
I need to use jquery.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$('a[href*="youtube"]')
```

For more selectors, see the [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) portion of the jQuery API.

Comment: @Ray Toal: done. (Though I find it odd that jQuery says that the quotes are "mandatory," despite the fact that the selector works perfectly without them.)

Answer (score 10):

[Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('a[href*="youtube"]');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can always use "filter":

```
var allYoutubes = $('a').filter(function() { return /youtube/.test(this.href); });
```

You *could* use a fancier selector, but this is simple and clear and possibly faster, as the library doesn't need to do the work of figuring out what your selector means. It's a matter of taste mostly.

Comment: just out of curiosity: can you explain this approach compared to the other answers here?

Comment: @Caspar: jQuery's [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) runs a test against all elements in the set. If the test is true, it keeps the element; if it's false, it throws it out. So this will select all `<a>` elements on the page and throw out any who fail the test (in this case, the test is "does the element's `href` attribute include 'youtube'?")

Comment: @reid, thanks for the explanation, but what I want to know what the difference is of this approach compared to the others., e.g efficiency, performance,  compatibility etc.

Comment: Ah now I see, this also can be made **case-insensitive** with an i option, excellent!

Answer (score 4):

pretty simple...

```
$('a[href*="youtube"]')
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

These other answers are great; but in case you're interested it's not that difficult to do a pure JS (no jQuery) alternative

```
function getYouTubeLinks() {

    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var ytlinks = [];
       for(var i=0,l=links.length;i<l;i++){
           if(links[i].href.replace("http://","").indexOf("youtube.com") === 0) {
            ytlinks.push(links[i]);  
           } 
        } 
   return ytlinks;
}

var youtube = getYouTubeLinks();
for(var i=0,l=youtube.length;i<l;i++){
    youtube[i].style.color = "pink";   
}
```

it'd be a good idea to make sure to strip out "www." and "https://" as well.

Comment: try to loop like this: `(i=0,l=links.length;i<l;i++)` so the length doesn't need to  bee evaluated all the time ;).

Comment: @Caspar good point. Feel free to edit the answer (if you don't I will, but it was your idea) - that's what SO's about after all.